# Spinner ignores conditional statements

Tags: android, spinner, if-statement

So i got my spinner with entries from a StringArray.

```
String[] spinnerEntries = {
                getResources().getString(R.string.oldPoint),
                getResources().getString(R.string.newPoint),
                getResources().getString(R.string.gpsLocation) };

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerEntries);
```

I want to set the `searchPoint` depending on spinner selection, but it totally igonores all cases except for the first one (oldPoint). What am I doing wrong? Wheter i got too tired or too stupid, but i just don't see the problem.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    String spinnerItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    if (spinnerItem.equals(getString(R.string.oldPoint))) {
        searchPoint = R.string.oldPoint;
    } else if (spinnerItem.equals(R.string.newPoint)) {
        searchPoint = R.string.newPoint;
    } else if (spinnerItem.equals(R.string.gpsLocation)) {
        searchPoint = R.string.gpsLocation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first conditional, you're correctly calling `getString`() on the constant name.  However, on the second two else blocks, you're not.

```
// Correct
if (spinnerItem.equals(getString(R.string.oldPoint))) {
    searchPoint = R.string.oldPoint;

// Need to call getString() on R.string.newPoint
} else if (spinnerItem.equals(R.string.newPoint)) {
    searchPoint = R.string.newPoint;

// Need to call getString() on R.string.gpsLocation
} else if (spinnerItem.equals(R.string.gpsLocation)) {
    searchPoint = R.string.gpsLocation;
}
```

Comment: Great! Well seems i'm just too tired, couldn't even find such a small thing. Thank You!